# How many factors does $36^2$ have

Tags: factoring

How many factors does $36^2$ have 
 
$(A)2 \\ (B)8 \\ (C)24 \\ (D)25 \\ (E)26$

---

$36^2=2^4\times3^4$
How do i count the number of factors?I don't know.

Comment: You certainly know howto make the list of all factors! Do that, and then count them.

Comment: Try to do that and maybe you'll be able to see a pattern.

Comment: Prime factors - same as $36$.

Comment: [This link](http://mathschallenge.net/library/number/number_of_divisors) may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The counting of factors is to be done in the following way:

As you have written, $$36^2=2^4 \times 3^4$$
Hence you have $4$ $2$'s and $4$ $3$'s as prime factors. So all factors of $36^2$ possible are different combinations of these $8$ factors.
To form the factors, you can choose one $2$, or two $2$'s, or three $2$'s, or four $2$'s, or none of them. 
 
So you have $4+1=5$ choices.
Similarly, you can choose one $3$, and so on. 
In this way, you have $(4+1)(4+1)$ choices for the $8$ prime factors. 
Thus the total number of factors = $(4+1)(4+1)=25$

Answer (score 3):

It can be written as $2^4.3^4$ so now total factors are $(p_1+1)(p_2+1)$ where $p_i$ represents powers of prime thus total factors $(4+1)(4+1)=25$ thus option D

Answer (score 2):

The question is ambiguous - do you mean *prime factors* or *divisors*?

---

If you mean *prime factors*, then $36^2$ has the same amount as $36$ (that is, $2$ prime factors).

---

If you mean *divisors*, then each of the $2$ prime factors can appear in each divisor between $0$ and $4$ times, hence there are $5^2=25$ divisors:

- $2^0\cdot3^0$
- $2^0\cdot3^1$
- $2^0\cdot3^2$
- $2^0\cdot3^3$
- $2^0\cdot3^4$
- $2^1\cdot3^0$
- $2^1\cdot3^1$
- $2^1\cdot3^2$
- $2^1\cdot3^3$
- $2^1\cdot3^4$
- $2^2\cdot3^0$
- $2^2\cdot3^1$
- $2^2\cdot3^2$
- $2^2\cdot3^3$
- $2^2\cdot3^4$
- $2^3\cdot3^0$
- $2^3\cdot3^1$
- $2^3\cdot3^2$
- $2^3\cdot3^3$
- $2^3\cdot3^4$
- $2^4\cdot3^0$
- $2^4\cdot3^1$
- $2^4\cdot3^2$
- $2^4\cdot3^3$
- $2^4\cdot3^4$

Comment: I do not see the question as ambiguous.  You are correct that $36$ and $36^2$ have the same prime factors.  However, an integer $m$ is said to be a factor of a positive integer $n$ if there exists an integer $k$ such that $km = n$.  An integer $m$ is said to be a divisor of an integer $n$ if there exists a unique integer $k$ such that $$\frac{n}{m} = k$$  Multiplying both sides of the equation by $k$ shows that $m$ is a factor of $n$ whenever it is a divisor.  The reverse is not true if $m = n = 0$.  However, when the divisor is not $0$, factors and divisors are the same.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I think it's a matter of terminology (English terminology if you will). To my understanding, a factor typically means **prime** factor, whereas a number $m$ that divides a number $n$ is typically referred to as a **divisor** of $n$. In any case, I gave an answer that addresses both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the prime decomposition of the number,

$$36^2=2^4\cdot3^4$$

you can form distinct factors by combining all possible multiplicities of the primes, including $0$, $2^0\cdot3^0,2^1\cdot3^0,\cdots2^3\cdot3^2\cdots2^4\cdot3^4$. There are $5\cdot5=25$ such combinations (counting $1$ and $36^2$).

More generally, there will be $(m_1+1)(m_2+1)\cdots(m_n+1)$ distinct factors for the  number $$p_1^{m_1}\cdot p_2^{m_2}\cdots p_n^{m_n}.$$

Comment: Crossed with @SchrodingersCat.

Answer (score 0):

Each factor of $36^2 = 2^43^4$ is of the form $2^{\alpha}3^{\beta}$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are integers satisfying the inequalities $0 \leq \alpha \leq 4$ and $0 \leq \beta \leq 4$.  Since there are five choices for each exponent, the number of factors of $1296$ is $5 \cdot 5 = 25$.

In general, if $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_k^{a_k} = \prod_{j = 1}^{k} p_j^{a_j}$, then each of its factors will be of the form $p_1^{b_1}p_2^{b_2} \cdots p_k^{b_k}$, where $b_j$ is an integer satisfying the inequalities $0 \leq b_j \leq a_j$ for $1 \leq j \leq k$.  Hence, $n$ will have $$\prod_{j = 1}^{k} (a_j + 1)$$ factors.